# Why connection is "pronounced" as C while "concert" is pronounced as K

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, consonants

I was wondering why **connection** is pronounced with **C** while **concert** is pronounced with **K**.

Comment: Take a look at the link in my previous comment.  We refer to the **"K"** version of _c_ as a _"hard C"_ and the **"S"** version as a _"soft C."_

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure where the '*soft C*' is in '*connection*'. Perhaps OP is referring to the '*sh*' sound in '*-tion*'

Comment: @p.s.w.g  I don't think there is a soft c - I just thought mentioning the hard and soft terminology might help him get started on the other page.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *as C*?

*Connection* is pronounced with the same initial **K** sound as *concert*.

By *as C* do you mean an **S** sound? If so, where did you encounter *connection* pronounced as **s**onnection?

Comment: I do wonder if the OP thinks the 'sh' sound after the 'c' is coming from the 'c'? Both of the 'C's in connection are, of course, hard. It is the 'tio' combination which makes the 'sh' sound, but that could be where the confusion lies...